# Need to batch detect, measure, calc DPI for a consistently placed ruler in large set of technical images

Tags: edge-detection

I have a large set of photographs of pieces of rocks. In each photo there is a 4 inch ruler bar placed next to the rock, consistently on the left near the edge, see example:

[image]

Over 10 years the photographers moved in and out, and used different file resolutions.

I need to normalize all of them to the same DPI before I can stitch them together.

I have approx 10,000 to process...

Thank you in advance and any thoughts?

R

Comment: What example do you mean?